# How to prove if $\frac{20b}{19b-20}=a$ is possible or not, where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

This is a follow up question to the one [posted here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561201/a-frac3bb-3-find-all-values-of-b-where-a-is-a-positive-integer/2561253#2561253). (The method posted here works for all cases where there isn't a coefficient in front of $b$ in the denominator)

**Here is the problem:**
$$\frac{20b}{19b-20}=a$$
$a$ and $b$ have to be positive integers. **Prove** whether the equation is possible or not possible. By the way, the answer is that it isn't possible.

**What I've attempted**
My first method was to check if $20b$ are divisible by $1$ or $5$. This didn't work, as you will see. We know $19b-20$ will never be $1$. I tried to check whether $19b - 20$ will be a multiple of $5$, however this approach was wrong, as it may be a multiple of $5$, but that does not mean that it is a factor of $20b$.

My second attempt was playing with the equation algebraically. I got to $20(b+a)=19(ba)$. This shows that $ba$ has to be even, however it does not prove whether the equation is possible or not.

I don't know how to approach these problems that require you to disprove the whether an expression is divisible, especially if the variables are both present in both the denominator and the numerator. Could someone please provide some assistance in proving/disproving this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should watch the video "problem 6" or something like that on the numberphile youtube channel. I seem to recall it being similar. It might give you ideas if you don't want an answer right away.

Comment: Here it is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y30VF3cSIYQ. I will watch it, but I don't think the problem I've posted will be that hard, as it is for high school level proofs.

Comment: It might be helpful to think of it as  $\dfrac 1a+\dfrac 1b=\dfrac {19}{20}$ so the problem is equivalent to whether $\dfrac {19}{20}$ can be expressed as a sum of two unit fractions ([Egyptian fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction)).

Comment: @hypergeometric That is actually what I am trying to prove: whether or not $\dfrac 1x+\dfrac 1y=\dfrac {19}{20}$ is possible. However I thought it would be easier if I could just prove that the equations of the form above was divisible. Would it actually make it harder?

Comment: @WeavingBird1917 - per [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=19%2F20+as+egyptian+fraction), $\dfrac {19}{20}=\dfrac 12+\dfrac 13+\dfrac 19+\dfrac 1{180}$, so looks like it's not possible! Alternatively, plot $20(x+y)=19xy$ and it is clear that when $x=2$, $y$ is not an integer, and when $y=2$, $x$ is not an integer. Also $x=\frac {20}{19}>1$ and $y=\frac {20}{19}>1$ are asymptotes. Hence there are no integer solutions.

Comment: @hypergeometric Thanks, from the looks of the equation above, it also does not look like its possible. $19b-20$ doesn't look like it will ever be a factor of $20b$, since $19b$ is so close to $20b$. However, I'm not sure how to prove that mathematically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b=1$, then we get $a=-20$ which is not a positive integer.

In the following, $b\ge 2$.

We have
$$a=\frac{20b}{19b-20}=\frac{19b-20+b+20}{19b-20}=1+\frac{b+20}{19b-20}$$

So, $\frac{b+20}{19b-20}$ has to be a positive integer.

Then, we have to have
$$\frac{b+20}{19b-20}\ge 1\implies b+20\ge 19b-20\implies 18b\le 40\implies b\le 2$$

If $b=2$, then we get $a=\frac{20}{9}$ which is not an integer.

Comment: Wow, that's a very nice way of showing it. Is that how you generally approach divisibility problems like this or is it just for this specific case?

Comment: @WeavingBird1917: Having the form $\frac{px+r}{qx+s}$ where $p\lt q$ often works.